# global variables not seen in SRAM arduino

Tags: arduino, global-variables

I am trying to print all the sram contents and i expect to find the global variables declared in the code to be at Ox100. But it seems like they are not allocated at all. granted i am not using the variables anywhere in the code but i would still expect them to be allocated memory. Another thing to note is that even if i keep adding var in the code the Global variable usage seems to hold steady with message below. What am i missing? Some compiler optimization?

**Global variables use 184 bytes (8%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1864 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.**

```
int var1 = 100;
int var2 = 100;
int var3 = 100;
int var4 = 100;
int var5 = 100;
int var6 = 100;

void setup() {
  UCSR0B = (1 << TXEN0);                  //Enable the serial output
  UBRR0L = 16;                            //Set the baud rate to 57600bps    
  memory_dump1();                      //Execute to the memory_dump subroutine

}

void loop(){
    int var2 = var1;
    delay(5000);
    memory_dump1();
  }

void memory_dump1(){
    uint16_t address;
  uint8_t byte_at_address, new_line;

   address = 0x0100;
 int byteCount = 0;


  while (address <= 0x08FF) {

    byte_at_address = *(byte *)address;
    Serial.print (byte_at_address,HEX);
        Serial.print ('\t');

    address++;
    byteCount ++;
    if ( byteCount % 8 == 0 ){
          Serial.print ('\n');

      }    
}
}
```

Comment: they are optimized away, because they are not used.

Comment: interesting, what would qualify as usage? refer them in a function?

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `volatile` might help...

```
// volatile  /*  9 byte, or 209 byte RAM if the // is removed  */
int dummy_data[100]; 
void setup() { }
void loop() { }
```

*Sample compiled for an Arduino Nano with IDE 1.8.9*

Answer (score 0):

```
int dummy_data[100] { 1,2,3,4,5,6 }; 

void dumpRAM (const char* name, void* adr, size_t size) {
    unsigned int iadr = (unsigned int) adr;
    Serial.print("0x"); 
    if (iadr < 0x1000) Serial.write('0');
    if (iadr < 0x100) Serial.write('0');
    if (iadr < 0x10) Serial.write('0');
    Serial.print (iadr, HEX);
    Serial.print (": ");   
    Serial.println (name);
    byte* bp = (byte*) adr;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size;) {
       Serial.write (' '); if(*bp <0x10) Serial.write('0');
       Serial.print( *bp++, HEX);
       if ( (++i & 0x0F) == 0) // every 16 byte
          Serial.println();
    }
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dumpRAM("dummy_data", dummy_data, sizeof(dummy_data));  
}
```

This helps to use your variable (thus avoids opitimizing it away), shows its content and address.